# Binary Search Python Spell Check

Tags: python, dictionary, binary

I am trying to import a text file (all lower-case words, no punctuation) and compare those words to a dictionary list of words. If a word does not appear in the dictionary list, it is printed as potentially incorrect. If a word does appear in the dictionary list, nothing is done. We are supposed to be using a binary search method here. I think my binary search method is correct, I just don't know where/how to return words that do not appear in the dictionary list and announce them as potentially incorrect.

Thank you!

My input file sentence: the quick red fox jumps over the lzy brn dog

```
def spellcheck(inputfile):

filebeingchecked=open(inputfile,'r')
spellcheckfile=open("words.txt",'r')

dictionary=spellcheckfile.read().split()
checkedwords=filebeingchecked.read().split()

for word in checkedwords:

    low = 0
    high=len(dictionary)-1

    while low <= high:

        mid=(low+high)//2
        item=dictionary[mid]

        if word == item:
            return word

        elif word < item:
            high=mid-1

        else:
            low=mid+1

    return word

def main():

    print("This program accepts a file as an input file and uses a spell check function to \nidentify any problematic words that are not found in a common dictionary.")
    inputfile=input("Enter the name of the desired .txt file you wish to spellcheck: ")

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `word == item`, you do not want to return that word. You want to break out of the while loop. However, there are two conditions for exiting a while loop:

1. When the word is in the dictionary, you break out of the while loop, or
2. When the word is not in the dictionary, eventually the while loop will end

So, how do we discern between the two? It turns out that in Python, there is an `else` clause for the `while` and `for` loop: the code in the else clause executes only when the loop ends naturally and not the result of a break statement, so that's what I use.

Also, to return more than one words, I can collect them in a list and return that list later, or I can use the `yield` keyword. See how it works below.

```
def spellcheck(inputfile):

    filebeingchecked=open(inputfile,'r')
    spellcheckfile=open("words.txt",'r')

    dictionary=spellcheckfile.read().split()
    checkedwords=filebeingchecked.read().split()

    for word in checkedwords:

        low = 0
        high=len(dictionary)-1

        while low <= high:

            mid=(low+high)//2
            item=dictionary[mid]

            if word == item:
                break

            elif word < item:
                high=mid-1

            else:
                low=mid+1
        else:
            yield word

def main():

    print("This program accepts a file as an input file and uses a spell check function to \nidentify any problematic words that are not found in a common dictionary.")
    inputfile=input("Enter the name of the desired .txt file you wish to spellcheck: ")
    for word in spellcheck(inputfile):
        print(word)

main()
```

Comment: I understand your use of the final `else: yield word` statement, however, the output comes back as follows: the quick red fox jumps the lzy brn dog (over is left out). Any idea why?

Comment: The output contains the *misspelled* words. Check your dictionary. Are those words in there? Is the dictionary really sorted?

Comment: I tried downloading a different dictionary and think the problem was that my previous one had some words (such as names, cities, whatever) capitalized possibly messing with the sorting. A new dictionary list of all lowercase words seemed to do the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try using a much smaller dictionary: use the input file, sort it and turn it into a dictionary. What do you see? Try to take a couple of words off that custom dictionary and observe.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search "ends" when the array you should be searching is empty. In your case, you are keeping track of the beginning and ending index of the array with `low` and `high`, and you are correct that you should keep searching `while low <= high`.

But what does it mean for the logic of your program when `(low <= high) == False` and you have not found a matching word?

It means this word is not in your dictionary and you should take the appropriate action (add it to the list of "incorrect words).

Of course, you only output the list of incorrect words once you have finished looking through all the words you were supposed to.